# soql of List<Task> and <Account>

Tags: apex, soql, schedule

Our incoming calls are saved as Tasks, and related to a temp account.

If the calling number already exists in an account, we want to relate that task to the account.

First, we make a list of the tasks under the temp account:

```
List<Task> tasklst = [SELECT id, Source_Number_Tech__c from task where subject like 'Incoming%' AND whatid = '0010O000000U0hfQAC' /*LIMIT 10*/];
```

Next, we make a list of existing accounts having that number(this step do not work):

```
List<Account> accountlst = [SELECT id, Phone from Account WHERE Phone in :tasklst];
```

Next, if the phone exists under an account, we want to update the task whatid accordingly:

```
if(accountlst.Size() >0{
//update Task's whatid according
```

How can I handle such request?
Also, how can we schedule such task to run daily- search if the task's phone exist in an account, if so, update task whatid.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate problem with the code you've shown here is that you're asking Salesforce to query Accounts

```
 WHERE Phone in :tasklst
```

But `tasklst` is a list of `Task` objects, not `String`s, and a `Phone` field holds a `String`. You would need to iterate over `tasklst` and add the field `Source_Number_Tech__c` to a `Set<String> phoneSet`. Then, you'd be able to query

```
WHERE Phone IN :phoneSet
```

More broadly, it looks like your code *may* have some logical or bulkification issues, but there's not enough context to provide a lot of commentary. The two implementation routes that seem reasonable to me would be either a trigger or a scheduled Batch Apex class running at night.

Whatever path you take, you'll need to ensure that you handle "many-to-many" matching:  more than one Task may match to any given Account, and you may have Tasks matching multiple Accounts in scope at any given time.